# Prove that $\sin^4(x)\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x)\cos^4(x) - \sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)=0.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Using the following expression:

$$\sin^4(x)\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x)\cos^4(x) - \sin^2(x)\cos^2(x).$$

The above expression is supposed to evaluate to zero, but how?

Comment: Regardless, the trick's just to factor out something, and you're left with something close to a trig identity. Also, like Jp said, that's an expression, not an equation

Answer (score 9):

**Hint:** All three terms have a factor of $\sin^2x\cos^2x$. What happens if you take this common factor out?

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\sin^4 x \cos^2 x + \sin^2 x\cos^4 x - \sin^2 x \cos^2 x&=\sin^2 x \cos^2 x\ (\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x - 1)\\
&=\sin^2 x \cos^2 x\ (1-1)\\
&=\large\color{blue}0.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Let $\sin^2(x) = y$.

Note that $\cos^2(x) = 1-\sin^2(x) = 1- y$.

Your expression now becomes:

$$y^2(1-y) + y(1-y)^2 - y(1-y) = y(1-y)(y + (1-y) - 1) = y(1-y)(0) = 0.$$